Prisma exclude field depends on another field
Question
i have schema model like this
model Question {
    id           String   @id @default(cuid())
    question     String
    createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
    is_anonymous Boolean

    createdBy   User     @relation(fields: [createdById], references: [id])
    createdById String
    Answer      Answer[]
}

and i have query like this
const answer = await ctx.db.answer.findUnique({
  where: { id: input.id },
  include: {
    createdBy: {
      select: { name: true, id: true, image: true, username: true },
    },
    Question: {
      include: {
        createdBy: {
          select: { name: true, id: true, image: true, username: true },
        },
      },
    },
    Answer: true,
    Like: userId
      ? {
          where: { userId },
          select: { id: true },
        }
      : false,
    _count: {
      select: { Like: true, Answer: true },
    },
  },
});

i want to include createdBy only if the question has the flag is_anonymous otherwise i don't want to populate the createdBy object
i tried to use prisma extension but i cannot achieve this with only prisma queries i had to modify the data manually so any idea how to it?
